# How can I resize a binary(64) image in odoo using ONLY xml code? (max-height)

Tags: css, xml, odoo, qweb

`<"span t-if="o.image is not NoneType" t-field="o.image" t-options-widget="&quot;image&quot;">`

I have tried using `style="max-height:115px"` but it doesn't work

I was able to resize using a max-height on an `<"img src="blah.blah">` but not with this binary.

i added random quotes to allow the code to show up here

Answer (score 1):

Define the `style` or the `class` inside `t-options`, you can find examples in [payment](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/payment/views/payment_portal_templates.xml#L106) module:

```
<span t-field="tx.acquirer_id.image_128" t-att-title="tx.acquirer_id.name"  
      role="img" t-att-aria-label="tx.acquirer_id.name" 
      t-options='{"widget": "image", "style":"max-width: 60px; display: inline-block"}'/>
```

and [website_sale](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/website_sale/views/templates.xml#L589) module:

```
<div t-if="product_variant" t-field="product_variant.image_128" 
     t-options="{'widget': 'image', 'qweb_img_responsive': False, 'class': 'rounded shadow o_alternative_product o_image_64_max' }" />
```